# Update database using the failed email delivery report

Tags: php, email

This might be very generic question but please go through it once, I need a piece of advice.
What I want to do is I've set the script on my website to allow users to invite their friends or family members. Now as they provide email addresses, script will send invitations to those email addresses, I'm using Swift Mailer for that.
Reward points are associated to every email they invite, so I can not ignore any undelivered emails. I get failed reports in my email but is there any way I can read them or have some trace & update the status in my database?
You may find it unusual but this is what my requirement is.
Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/ to process you incoming email and recognize undelivered once. Should be pretty easy.

EDIT 
Get email inbox

```
<?php
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'davidwalshblog@gmail.com';
$password = 'davidwalsh';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
```

Comment: It seems it requires root installation on server, if that's the case, I won't be able to do it.

Comment: yes you will need a root access to capture your emails. I don't see any other way... unless you can connect to your inbox from php and and all new messages. From those filter the undelivered once and update db. see my edit

Comment: Warning: imap_open() [function.imap-open]: Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in /home/public_html/example.com/email.php on line 8
Cannot connect to Gmail: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Connection refused

Comment: could be firewall, if you have ssh access to your server to to telnet imap.gmail.com on 993

Comment: Yeah I thought the same & I don't have SSH access unfortunately :(

Comment: well, the only advice I can give is get a better hosting ;)

Comment: Hehe, well a good thing is it works with my domain, so if I change the host to mine (and that's what I need), it works perfectly fine. No errors :)

Comment: Can you give some advice over how to run a search for finding undelivered reports & their associated email address?

Comment: Never done it myself, you can use the https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/ to get info from headers, etc. You have to find a pattern.